# How to use an input field as query parameter to a destination?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For my sample Google Chrome extension, I have a textbox and a link:

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25" />
<a class="button" href="http://www.google.com"><span>Search</span></a>
```

When the user clicks on the link, I want the browser to actually go to:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=<whatever was in textbox>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Added google-chrome tags again, any suggestions specific to Chrome are also welcome..

Comment: How is the substance of your question or the proposed solutions dependent upon Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advice you to use an ordinary form with a submit button for this. In that case, you even don't have to use JavaScript at all. For example:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input id="textbox" name="q" type="text" value="" size="25" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

If you really want to use the provided markup, best thing you can do is to add an ID to the `a` element, e.g. `searchButton`, and then do:

```
document.getElementById("searchButton").onclick = doSearch;

function doSearch() {
    var v = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(v);
    return false; // not entirely necessary, but just in case
}
```

Comment: That would work if the user was submitting a form, but he's not. The user actually clicks on an anchor tag.

Comment: @Bryan: You're right, though it's a bad design pattern. The OP should use a button for this. I will change my answer.

Comment: @Marcel - I agree it is poor design because any robot crawling the site will follow the link (they don't follow forms, usually), it isn't 503c, will fail usability if CSS is turned off, *and* isn't what anchors are for. ;)

Comment: @Marcel: Strange thing - as soon as I add an id to the anchor, the CSS setting `a.button` do not apply anymore. Is this expected? Any known workarounds?

Comment: @Marcel: Nevermind, I accidentally removed the href part while trying something, and I thought it was because I added the id part.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/wdVQ5/)'s an example with inline javascript that sets the href of the link appropriately and then lets normal processing handle the redirect (added encodeURIComponent base on Marcel's comment).

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25" />
<a class="button" id="googleLink" href="willBeChanged" 
 onclick="this.href='http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);">
  <span>Search</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent` to properly encode query parameters. Moreover, it's a bad design pattern to put (lots of) code in your markup.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel Thanks for the suggestions.  Also, thanks @BryanH for adding the code.  I've updated it to have encodeURIComponent as well.  As far as not having too much inline JavaScript, I agree, but originally Lazer said he was making an extension, so I thought he might like it self-contained in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to make your life easy.

Your JQuery would look like this:

```
$("#linky").attr('href',"http://www.google.com/search?q="+$("#textbox").val());
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25"></input>
<a class="button" href="www.google.com" id="linky"><span>Search</span></a>
```

Comment: So if someone types "foo" in the box, the value of the link would be `foo`, not `http://www.google.com/search?q=foo`

Comment: Bryan, how so?  But my answer was sloppy because it needs to be tied to an action... Basically you need to tie in my jquery code into a function that runs when the textbox is changed. `$("#textbox").change( function() { // OLD CODE HERE });`

Comment: Please don't use jQuery solutions when the question isn't marked jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#textbox").keyup(function () {
  var searchstring = $(this).val();
  searchstring = encodeURIComponent(searchstring);

  $('#searchlink').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + searchstring);
  });

   });
```

HTML markup:

```
   <input id="textbox" type="text"  size="25">
   <a class="button" href="http://www.google.com" id='searchlink'>Search</a>
```

Comment: Please don't use jQuery solutions when the question isn't marked jQuery.